# Get to know the Code of Conduct

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, blog, code-of-conduct

In the latest blog post, Tim introduces us to the new Code of Conduct with multiple links to it. Presumably. Since the links don't work.

> our [brand new Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) (CoC) is rolling off the press

...

> Really, please, [take a moment to read the new Code of Conduct now](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

That link (they both point to the same address) gives me a Page not Found.

Is the link incorrect? Did the CoC simply go down in an inconvenient moment? What went wrong?

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313694/269301) posted while I was still writing mine. Leaving it here as signpost.

Comment: (gnat hoping that this will be tagged [meta-tag:status-bydesign])

Comment: This reminds me of the South Park episode where Cartman gets his own theme park and then creates a huge commercial buzz for it by actively advertising that other people can't get in.

Comment: You can only read it if you're welcoming enough ;)

Comment: Still getting a 404 hours later.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, although in fairness, it's still early on the American continent. I'd prefer they started fixing this after morning coffee, not before it.

Comment: @Mast: Personally, I'd have preferred they fix it before they publicized the link, but that's just me. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Naturally. And this is why you don't push to production a minute before you leave the building.

Comment: In a sudden turn of events, the blog post itself seems to have disappeared, since the link's still in the sidebar but it leads to a "Page not found"

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank: Everything works as intended according to the **C**ode **o**f **C**haos. **C**an't **o**pen **C**oc is just a part of it.

Comment: Confirmed in browser history that [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct) has disappeared.

Comment: Turns out they ran into a bit of a [time zone problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313727/269301).

Comment: @Mast, I think you meant "North American continent", there are two American continents, that's not very welcoming... ;-)

Comment: @smci Last I checked those continents were right above each other on the map. Since we were talking timezones, it turns into a matter of either/both/whichever. But sure, this is the kind of flak you get for wanting to be more inclusive. Didn't want to exclude any employee even remotely in the vicinity of the USA (from here, that's up till and including Argentina). But *of-course* Muricans are taking it the wrong way. It's bloody impossible to do anything right in the comments since the new CoC! *wink wink smileyface*

Comment: @Mast: not really, South America is southeast of North America, and two time zones ahead http://fortunedream.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/united-states-time-zones-map-maps-south-zone-north-free-printable-america.jpg

Comment: @smci Oh, oops...

Answer (score 11):

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, [Tim Post says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313727/134729):

> There was an error scheduling the blog post. Somehow (we're looking into it), the time zone that the post scheduler used was flipped, so what was supposed to go out at 1PM EDT actually went out much sooner.
>
> We've un-published the post until the actual routes go live, at which time the post scheduler (should) simply publish it at 1:00 PM today (EDT), which was chosen because it gives everyone involved ample time to make sure everything actually, you know, works.
>
> We have yet to identify the actual culprit, but one employee has reported feeding a strange furry pet past midnight after getting it wet, so we're chasing that lead with a bit of optimism.

**Update:** The new CoC is now live: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Upvote for Gremlins reference, even if indirect.

Comment: Yeah the rest of this is gibberish and nonsense. I upvote the gremlins reference.